# the program is skipping generating a two all togher and just doing a three

Tags: c#

The random function is way out of order with the generates.
When the computer generates a two it is supposed to be paper and say computer wins or something along those lines and it is generating paper but a three for the number instead of a two.

```
public partial class frmRPS : Form
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int myWin;
    int myTie;
    int myLoss;

    private void btnRock_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        picRockYou.Visible = true;
        picPaperYou.Visible = false;
        picScissorsYou.Visible = false;
        int Computer;
        Computer = rnd.Next(4);
        if (Computer == 1)
        {
            picRockComputer.Visible = true;
            picPaperComputer.Visible = false;
            picScissorsComputer.Visible = false;
            lblOutput.Text = "You Tied Nice Job";
            myTie += 1;
            lblTies.Text = myTie.ToString();
            lblOutput.Visible = true;
        }
        if (Computer == 2)
        {
            picRockComputer.Visible = false;
            picPaperComputer.Visible = true;
            picScissorsComputer.Visible = false;
            lblOutput.Text = "Computer Wins You Lost Try Again";
            myLoss += 1;
            lblLoss.Text = myLoss.ToString();
            lblOutput.Visible = true;
        }
        if (Computer == 3)
        {
            picRockComputer.Visible = false;
            picPaperComputer.Visible = false;
            picScissorsComputer.Visible = true;
            lblOutput.Text = "Congratulations You Won!";
            myWin += 1;
            lblWins.Text = myWin.ToString();
            lblOutput.Visible = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zd1bc8e5(v=vs.110).aspx,
return value of .Next(int maxValue) is

`A 32-bit signed integer that is greater than or equal to 0, and less than maxValue`

you're not processing 0 value

Potential fix:

```
Computer = rnd.Next(3) + 1;
```

Comment: read the comment, he said he already tried this